# io.invertase.gradle.build version: '1.5' was not found, react-native

Tags: android, react-native, npm, gradlew

I have a react-native project which had below error when i try to run project with

`react-native run-android` or `cd adnroid > gradlew assembleDebug` every case i got that error,

```
What went wrong: Plugin [id: 'io.invertase.gradle.build', version: '1.5'] was not found in any of the following sources:
    Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
    Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'io.invertase.gradle.build:io.invertase.gradle.build.gradle.plugin:1.5') Searched in the following repositories: Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I tried `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` delete and `re-install` all modules but still i have same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this error because the dependent packages in android could not load due to the wrong configuration related to the proxy, because of my problem. After configuring it was fixed.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit further what you mean when you say wrong configuration related to the proxy?

This suddenly started happening on our ci today (github actions) and made our builds fail. A few hours ago this wasn't an issue, and our android builds were building fine.

As far as we know we have no proxy anywhere (!?!)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Try to clean the cache of the metro development server. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

V1.5 is available and latest version so there is no issue in that. Find the latest version below,
*https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.invertase.gradle.build*

**The issue is:**
Your proxy blocked this package to download. I was facing the same issue and tried to switch to my mobile hotspot/network instead of office network and It worked.
No config change I made.